# Update categories URL to new domain

Tags: wordpress, url, hyperlink, categories

Recently I have changed my domain to another server, along with the hosting and all the files, I have copied them to the new hosting and updated the database, but the url of the menus or the categories of my site continue to give me those of the old domain. How can I change the URLs of the categories to the new address without having to redo everything?

it was and still is (wrong)

https://oldomain.com/?cat=5

and must be

https://newdomain.com/?cat=5

Comment: Try to update your permalinks.

Comment: permalinks shows the right domain name,  i changed and then refresh the page and change it back again and still not working. There is any other option?

Comment: check permission in your htaccess file

Comment: Done!!!! Problem solved. It was a simple permission problem. Thanks